# javascript error apostrophe

Tags: javascript

i have in my jsp a js function to open a popup, in this function I pass as parameter, this parameter is a message like this

> L'appareil est en panne

but when i load my page i have a javascript. how i can i do before i load my page to do this*

> L''appareil est en panne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape quotes inside strings using backslashes:

```
alert('L\'appareil est en panne\'');
```

there's a [Java class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/StringEscapeUtils.htm) that seems to do the job: `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript()`. Boy, you Java guys have a class for everything!

Comment: @Mercer I don't know much Java but I'm sure there's a built-in method to escape a string.

Comment: @Mercer is this any good? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/StringEscapeUtils.htm

Comment: Javascript is not the same as Java. Either way, try

System.out.println("L\'appareil est en panne");

Comment: @Nubsis I think the OP wants to output a string from Java that is going to be interpreted in Javascript.

Comment: thx it's work

StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(unescapedJavaScript));

Answer (score 0):

Altough your question is not very clear. But you can use escape character \' to resolve such problems.

Comment: sorry for my bad english, but i create my message in a java class so i want to replace my ' with escape but how can i do

Comment: can you paste in some code. I believe i can help you with it.

Comment: String str = "L'appareil est en panne";
str.replaceAll("'","\');

System;out.println(str);  
in the console:
L'appareil est en panne

don't work :(

Comment: i use the Pekka solution

StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(unescapedJavaScript));

it's work for me thx for yur response